# JQuery select image from gallery based on selected option in dropdown

Tags: jquery, dropdown

I have image gallery based on [lightSlider](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/) and i trying to make that when I select value from dropdown, image from gallery with same value as my id is displayed (bring to focus):

gallery:

```
 <ul id="image-gallery" class="gallery">
     <li value="id1" data-thumb="images/72x72.jpg">
         <img  src="images/340x400.jpg" /> </li>
     <li value="id2" data-thumb="images/72x72.jpg">
         <img  src="images/340x400.jpg" /> </li>
     <li value="id3" data-thumb="images/72x72.jpg">
         <img src="images/340x400.jpg" /> </li>
     <li value="id4" data-thumb="images/72x72.jpg">
         <img  src="images/340x400.jpg" /> </li>
     <li value="id5" data-thumb="images/72x72.jpg">
         <img src="images/340x400.jpg" /> </li>
</ul>
```

and dropdown:

```
<div class="styled-select">

 <select class="show-labels">
     <option id="id1" value="1"> 1</option>
     <option id="id2" value="2"> 2</option>
     <option id="id3" value="3"> 3</option>
     <option id="id4" value="4"> 4</option>
     <option id="id5" value="5"> 5</option>
 </select>
```

I dont have idea how to do it. I picked value of id from selected option, but dont know what to do next when I need select (and bring to focus) image with same value, and in other case, change dropdown value to selected item value when i click on image in gallery.

My attempt:

```
$(function () {
$('.styled-select').on('change', function () {
    var value = $('.show-labels').children(":selected").attr("id");
   alert(value); /*just for check if it's working*/
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Iam not sure that iam understand you right.
So check it out: `jsfiddle.net/pleinx/17urshcc/`

Now it changes the image-src on the selected item in your dropdown. The image-src will be replaced by the "data-thumb" value.

Comment: I may have been unclear. I want to show the picture in the gallery (bring it in focus) when I pick a dropdown id with same value as the value atrr in gallery list